# python for loop with array in condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I found that python doesn't have C style for loop:

```
  for (var;condition:increment)
```

For a simple for loop, I can use

```
  for i in xrange(number):
```

to produce

```
  for (i;i<number;i++)
```

however, if i have

```
  for (i = 2; an_array[i - 2] < number; i++)
```

how can I produce it in python?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

1. iterate over that array and use one of the neat functions in `itertools`, such as [`takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

   ```
   for item in takewhile(lambda i: i < number, array[2:]):
       # do stuff
   ```

   This takes values from the given iterable (here: an array) until (resp. while) **its contents** meet a certain condition.

   Here, `item` is the *content* of the respective array entry. If you really need the indexes, you can combine it with `enumerate()`:

   ```
   for index, item in enumerate(takewhile(lambda i: i < number, array[2:])):
       # do stuff
   ```

   But this index is off by 2, because it counts the items passed through; as you start with `array[2:]` you'll have to add `2` in order to access the right part of the array.
2. Use a while loop:

   ```
   i = 2
   while (array[i-2] < number):
       # do stuff
       i += 1
   ```

Comment: `enumerate` gained a starting index value (`start=0`) in Python 2.6, which makes the second version a bit nicer: `for index, item in enumerate(takewhile(lambda i: i < number, array[2:]), start=2):`.  Note that slicing the array makes a copy; if the array tends to be very large and efficiency is important you could use `itertools.islice` as well.  But I'd probably just start with method 2, the `while` loop, for readability. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
for i in xrange(2, number):
    # Whatever
```

When xrange takes 2 parameters, it creates a range from the first value to the last value. Note that the first value is included while the last value is not.

EDIT: If you're working with an array, Tim Pietzcker's method is the way to go. I just gave this method to provide a convenient counterpart.

Comment: What about the `an_array[i - 2] < number` breaking condition?